# Json.NET Deserialize value as Null or empty Array

Tags: .net, deserialization, json.net

In my application I'm interacting with external json service.

```
 /// simple response class
 public class AllForm
    {
        [JsonProperty("HOTELS")]
        public Hotel[] Hotels
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

This works greate when 'HOTELS' contains data.
But service return 'HOTELS:false' for empty collection. So I've deserialization exception. 
How can I resolve this case(deserialize to null or empty collection)?

Answer (score 0):

`HOTELS:false` is not same as `HOTELS:null` or `HOTELS:[]`. You need to do some custom deserialization or change the service to return properly

Comment: I know the difference, but it's external service. Whether there is still some way apart custom deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic types, namely:

```
    void DeserializeArrayOrBool(string json)
    {
        var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

        if (data["HOTELS"].GetType() == typeof(System.Boolean))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empty array");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HOTELS[0]={0} HOTELS[1]={1}", data["HOTELS"][0], data["HOTELS"][1]);
        }
    }

    public void DerializeArrayOrBool()
    {
        DeserializeArrayOrBool(@"{""HOTELS"":[123, 456]}");
        DeserializeArrayOrBool(@"{""HOTELS"":false}");
    }
```